# Code Igniter: Adding built in CI functions to a table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am attempting to add some styling to a table in Code Igniter, I realize CI has a built in table library to help achieve this. I'm unsure how to implement this in my specific implementation however. I'm looking to incorporate these inbuilt functions:

```
$this->load->library('table');
$this->table->set_heading(array('Name', 'Color', 'Size'));
```

How can I add those functions in my specific implementation?

I have the following controller:

```
    public function ecomma(){

        $this->load->model('report_model');
        $data ['query'] = $this->report_model->generate_ecomm_data_report();

        $this->load->view('report_view', $data);    
}
```

My view:

```
<table>
<tbody>

<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
<tr>

    <td><?php echo $row->no_skus; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->brand; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->unique_models; ?></td>

</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Table library is quite easy. This example requires that `generate_ecomm_data_report()`returns the results of a query. For example:

```
return $this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');
```

Controller:

```
public function ecomma(){
    $this->load->library('table');
    $this->load->model('report_model');

    $query = $this->report_model->generate_ecomm_data_report();
```

One advantage to the Table library is that styling is quite easy using the template scheme of the class. For instance to add a CSS class to the header and to rows.

controller continues:

```
    $my_styles = array(
              "thead_open" => "<thead class='my_style'>",
              "row_start' => '<tr class='my-row-style'>");
    $this->table->set_template($my_styles);

    $this->table->set_heading(array('Name', 'Color', 'Size'));
    $data[table] = $this->table->generate($query);

    $this->load->view('report_view', $data);    
 }
```

View:

```
 <?php echo isset($table) ? $table : "No Data"; ?>
```

The result will be a table structure like the one you create in the `foreach` loop - only this one has style.